# error connecting to mongo atlas from render

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas, render.com

I was trying to deploy node js app on render web service. I have added Static Outbound IP Addresses to network access in mongo atlas dashboard and I have added mongoatlas url from my mongo atlas account:

```
mongodb+srv://user:********@cluster0.65das3g.mongodb.net/app?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

when I clicked on deploy, the node is running, but connecting to database is failing with the following error message:

```
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM  MongoServerError: bad auth : authentication failed
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM      at Connection.onMessage (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:202:26)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM      at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:61:60)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM      at MessageStream.emit (events.js:376:20)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM      at processIncomingData (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:124:16)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM      at MessageStream._write (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:33:9)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM      at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM      at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM      at TLSSocket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:745:22)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM      at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:376:20)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM      at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12) {
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM    ok: 0,
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM    code: 8000,
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM    codeName: 'AtlasError',
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM    connectionGeneration: 0,
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM    [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(2) { 'HandshakeError', 'ResetPool' }
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM  }
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM  (node:77) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoServerError: bad auth : authentication failed
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM      at Connection.onMessage (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:202:26)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM      at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:61:60)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM      at MessageStream.emit (events.js:376:20)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM      at processIncomingData (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:124:16)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM      at MessageStream._write (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:33:9)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM      at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM      at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM      at TLSSocket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:745:22)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM      at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:376:20)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM      at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM  (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM  (node:77) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
Aug 26 08:17:47 PM  (node:77) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```